# Como adicionar ou remover um elemento de vetor?

Tags: c, array

De um vetor, como posso remover ou adicionar um elemento?

Comment: Você quer dizer no sentido de redimensionar o array ou há uma lógica a ser mantida no seu array, mantendo uma estrutura de dados?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT, poderia [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer o problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes como alguma tentativa de solução. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Não podes remover um elemento de um vetor.

Imagina que o vetor é como um parque de estacionamento e os seus lugares. Não podes remover um lugar, apenas podes mudar o conteúdo de cada lugar.

Uma coisa aproximada que podes fazer com o vetor, é saber quantos elementos estão "ocupados", e manter esses elementos no principio do vetor.

```
int vetor[100]; // capacidade para 100 elementos
size_t nvetor = 0; // zero elementos

vetor[nvetor++] = 42; // vetor[0] = 42;
vetor[nvetor++] = -1; // vetor[1] = -1;
vetor[nvetor++] = 0;  // vetor[2] = 0;
```

Para "remover" o vetor[1], podes fazer o seguinte

```
// copia elementos para tras
for (int k = 1; k < nvetor - 1; k++) vetor[k] = vetor[k + 1];
// ajusta nvetor
nvetor--;
```

Para verificação

```
for (k = 0; k < nvetor; k++) printf("%d ", vetor[k]);
```